# Serving food at Kiruv Events and OC 169:2

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, kiruv-outreach

In [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 169:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.169.2?lang=bi) the following is noted:

(*Source Provided by [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org)*)

> (**לֹא יִתֵּן לֶאֱכֹל אֶלָּא לְמִי שֶׁיּוֹדֵעַ בּוֹ שֶׁיְּבָרֵךְ**, הגה: וְיֵשׁ מְקִלִּין אִם נוֹתֵן לְעָנִי בְּתוֹרַת צְדָקָה (הר''י סוֹף פֶּרֶק אֵלּוּ דְּבָרִים
>
> ***One should only give food to be eaten to someone who knows how to make the blessing (on the food)** REMA: There are those who are lenient who say if you give it to a poor person as charity (it is permitted)*

## My Question

It is very popular in a variety of [outreach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Judaism_outreach) events to provide refreshments and food even in a non-Shabbos meal setting<sup>1</sup> (e.g. sushi, cookies, drinks, etc.).

This being said, under these circumstances it is unlikely to assure that those who do not know how to bless make a blessing<sup>2</sup>.

With the above noted, is there a *Heter* which Kiruv organizations use when serving food at an event which is likely that the large majority of participants will not recite a blessing on the food they are eating in light of the *Shulchan Aruch* and *Rema* quoted<sup>3</sup>?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>In a Shabbos meal setting, the host would be able to relieve the guests of their obligation with his blessings on wine and bread. Which would not be common in a case of a event where only light refreshments would be served.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Additionally I have heard (for what its worth) of people involved in Kiruv that making non-practicing Jews make blessings before they eat in a non-ceremonial setting will give the impression that Judaism is too demanding for them, thus causing them to abandon the possibility of becoming a practicing jew.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> I presume if there is a *Heter*, it would be based on the *Rema* but I am unsure how it would work</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

R Gil Student addresses this question [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2004/08/feeding-non-observant/) and, following a recap of the gemara and Shulkhan Aruch you cite, responds **the posekim have unanimously permitted this, but their rationales vary**

> R. Moshe Feinstein (Iggeros Moshe, Orah Hayim vol. 5 no. 13) rules
>   that **one should ask the person to recite a blessing but, if he
>   refuses, to serve him food anyway** so as not to have him think that
>   religious Jews lack basic manners. However, one should ask again, in
>   future cases, that the person recite a blessing before eating.
>
> R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Minhas Shlomo, vol. 1 no. 35) writes that
>   **if asking someone to recite a blessing will so offend him that he will
>   start to hate observant Jews, it is better not to ask him to do so.**
>
> R. Shmuel Wosner (Shevet Ha-Levi, vol. 4 no. 17) writes that **this is
>   only a rabbinic prohibition and may be set aside so as not to
>   antagonize a non-observant Jew**, particularly if he might otherwise eat
>   non-kosher food.
>
> R. Moshe Shternbuch (Teshuvos Ve-Hanhagos, vol. 1 no. 483) takes the
>   long view and states that **kiruv, bringing a fellow Jew closer to
>   Torah, in the long run creates less violations than otherwise so it is
>   a good thing to offer a non-observant Jew food even if he will not
>   recite a blessing before eating** [...]
>
> R. Shammai Gross (Shevet Ha-Kehasi, vol. 4 no. 329) writes that **the
>   prohibition is only when one knows for certain that the person will
>   not recite a blessing**. With a non-observant Jew, it is a mitzvah to
>   invite him for a meal and to serve him food. At worst, the giver can
>   recite a blessing out loud so as to be exempt everyone within earshot [...]
>
> R. Ya’akov Kamenetsky (Emes Le-Ya’akov on Orah Hayim 169 n. 197) is
>   quoted as saying that **it is more important to feed someone kosher
>   food, and thereby prevent him from eating forbidden food, that to be
>   concerned about him not reciting a blessing**. However, he adds that
>   there is no need to be concerned that he might come to hate religious
>   Jews because if we explain properly he should understand our concern.
>
> R. Eliezer Waldenberg (Tzitz Eliezer, vol. 22 no. 3) argues that **there
>   is no issue of lifnei iveir in this case because people can always
>   find food elsewhere**. The only issue is of mesaye’a, and R. Waldenberg
>   dismisses this concern based on the ruling of the Shakh (Yoreh Deah
>   151:6) that mesaye’a does not apply to someone who regularly violates
>   this prohibition (cf. Dagul Me-Revavah, ad loc.). Therefore, there is
>   absolutely no prohibition against giving food to someone who never
>   recites a blessing on the food. The only concern is with someone who
>   sometimes recites a blessing and sometimes does not. To him, there is
>   a prohibition against giving the food because he might not recite a
>   blessing.

Comment: check out also, [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/01/directions-on-shabbos/).