# May one gift food to a non-religious Jew if she does not say the Brachah?

Tags: halacha, food, non-religious

I would like to give a gift to a professor of mine who is a non-religious Jew. May I give her [kosher] chocolate? The halachic issue I am concerned about is that she will not say a bracha beforehand.

Comment: אתי עשה ודחי לא תעשה - a good mitzvah overrides a negative one. That's what the Gemmorah in Yevomos teaches us. But don't take it as a Halacha.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88070/759

Comment: My olam haba is the olam haze of my friend.

Comment: There's a really easy solution. Share the chocolate, and you make the bracha for both of you having her in mind. And, I'm pretty sure she won't mind sharing. If she does, maybe consider a different friend, next time.